Typo3 Upgrade 8.7.9 to ^9.5
I have taken over a very outdated Typo 3 8.7.9 installation from a web agency. I have now moved it to a new web server. I proceeded as follows:

empty Composer installation in the www folder of version 8.7.9.
copy the data from the old web server from the public folder to the new public folder
importing the DB

The website was then fully usable in the frontend and backend. Now I have started the upgrade to ^9.5 using composer and the official guide. I have been working on this for some time now and have already been able to fix a few bugs.
The installation tool no longer has any open Upgrade Wizard tasks. The frontend is also accessible. However, when calling the backend, the following error occurs for which I cannot find a solution:
#1294585866 InvalidArgumentException
No class named TYPO3\CMS\Cshmanual\Service\JavaScriptService

My composer.json from the www directory looks like this:
{
"repositories": [
    { "type": "composer", "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/" }
],
"name": "typo3/cms-base-distribution",
"description" : "TYPO3 CMS Base Distribution",
"license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
"config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
        "typo3/class-alias-loader": true,
        "typo3/cms-composer-installers": true,
        "helhum/typo3-console-plugin": true
    },
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.4"
    }
},
"require": {
    "helhum/typo3-console": "^5.5.5",
    "typo3/cms-backend": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-core": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-extbase": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-extensionmanager": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-filelist": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-fluid": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-frontend": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-install": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-recordlist": "^9.5",
    "gridelementsteam/gridelements": "^9.8",
    "georgringer/news": "^8.6",
    "evoweb/recaptcha": "^9.1",
    "friendsoftypo3/typo3db-legacy": "^1.1.1",
    "typo3/cms-adminpanel": "^9.2",
    "typo3/cms-rsaauth": "^9.5",
    "typo3fluid/fluid": "2.7.4",
    "psr/cache": "^1.0",
    "typo3/minimal": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-about": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-belog": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-beuser": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-felogin": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-form": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-impexp": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-info": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-scheduler": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-setup": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-sys-note": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-t3editor": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-viewpage": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-redirects": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-reports": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-seo": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-cshmanual": "*"
},
"scripts":{
    "typo3-cms-scripts": [
        "typo3cms install:generatepackagestates",
        "typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "@typo3-cms-scripts"
    ]
}
}

How can I fix this error? Or should I move the site to the new location another way

This is just a try because it helped in another thread: delete the folders vendor, typo3, and composer install again. https://www.typo3forum.net/discussion/84139/upgrade-von-8-7-auf-9-5-14-kein-backend-login

TYPO3 System extension typo3/cms-cshmanual does not exists in
TYPO3 v9 anymore, but is listed using the death-star * version
constraint. That could lead some missmatch.
Remove that extension first:
composer remove "typo3/cms-cshmanual": "*"

After that, check if really system extensions are installed in the correct version:
composer info | grep 'typo3\/cms-`

which should list the remaining core extensions along with the version.

copy the data from the old web server from the public folder to the new public folder

Does this contain coping the typo3conf/ext/ folder too ? That should be cleared and afterwards the
composer install

command executed again to ensure that extensions are installed from composer.

#1294585866 InvalidArgumentException
No class named TYPO3\CMS\Cshmanual\Service\JavaScriptService

That exception code is thrown within the GeneralUtility::callUserFunction() which could point to some extension calling that along with the JavaScript Service thingy at some point.
You should try to enable BE/FE debug mode to retrieve the full strack trace,
which gives indications where the root casue of this issue is triggerd, and not at which place the cure break out (throw exception).
Beside that, you should also execute the upgrade wizards after importing the database data.
